# Como incorporar Vue a Laravel 5.7 desde 0

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

Llevo algunos dias intentando incorporar Vue a mi proyecto en laravel, pero por algun motivo, no ha funcionado de la manera correcta, nunca he usado ni trabajado Vue, por lo que recurrí a la documentación y blogs para instalarlo, pero no he podido hacer que funcione correctamente, al no trabajarlo, no se que errores estoy presentando, por lo que me gustaría que me explicaran su uso e instalación desde cero.
Cuento con npm 6.6.0 y node 10.15.0

Answer (score 1):

**Para entender todo el proceso (usuarios no tan principiantes):**

Vue viene incluido por defecto en las dependencias del frontend, más especificamente en package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.15.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17"
}
```

En la configuración de mix (Wrapper de Laravel para Webpack) se incluye y se instancia Vue, más exactamente en resources/js/app.js

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

// ...

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Conociendo esta información, lo que hay que hacer es:

1. Obtener las dependencias ejecutando `npm install`
2. Compilar los assets, según el ambiente en el que estés: `npm run dev`
3. Tener un elemento «contenedor» con el id app en las vistas de blade, algo así: `<div id="app"></div>`

---

**Para principiantes o para quien necesita algo rápido:**

Desde hace varias veriones 5.x, Laravel incluye los assets precompilados en **/js/app.js**, por lo cual tan solo necesitas llamar esta ruta en tu vista principal de blade y puedes obviar los dos primeros puntos del procedimiento enunciado arriba.

Comment: Pasa que hice eso, pero por algun motivo los componentes no cargan y me aparece este error [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

Comment: ¿Cuáles componentes? eso es un problema distinto al planteado en la pregunta. Una cosa es incluir Vue, otra que no funcionen los componentes.

Comment: Como habia dicho antes, no se que error es ese, y no se como manejarlo

Comment: Entonces hay que plantear bien las preguntas, el título y la descripción dicen algo muy distinto a lo que está explicando en los comentarios.

Comment: No es nada diferente, di referencia de lo unico que poseo de informacion respecto al tema, y el problema inicio desde que intente usar los componentes de vue, por lo que deduje que era por eso, por lo que no tiene sentido decir que no es lo que estoy diciendo en la pregunta...